# Возвращение логического типа из вложенного запроса MSSQL 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server

## Добрый день

---

**Необходимо вернуть вернуть логическое значение из подзапроса в виде нового столбца в области выборки столбцов** 
**А так же преобразовать результат в "Да" или "Нет" для пользователей**

---

**Сведения о системе**

Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio                      12.0.5000.0
Клиентские средства служб Microsoft Analysis Services                       12.0.5000.0
Компоненты доступа к данным (MDAC)                      6.3.9600.17415
Microsoft MSXML                     3.0 5.0 6.0
Microsoft Internet Explorer                     9.11.9600.20477
Microsoft .NET Framework                        4.0.30319.42000
Операционная система                        6.3.9600

---

```
use ELMA3
SELECT TOP 1000 
        fz.[Id]
      ,[FIO]
      ,kadr.TipTrudoustroystva
      ,kadr.Organizaciya
      ,kadr.Dolzhnostj
      ,(SELECT Sotrudnik FROM GrafikOtpuskov WHERE Sotrudnik = fz.Id) as otp

  FROM [ELMA3].[dbo].[FizicheskieLica] as fz
  INNER JOIN FizicheskieLica_KadrovayaIst AS kadr ON kadr.Parent = fz.Id 
  AND (kadr.TipTrudoustroystva = 'Основное' OR kadr.TipTrudoustroystva = 'Совмещение') 
  AND (kadr.DataUvoljneniya >= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) OR kadr.DataUvoljneniya is null)
  WHERE (fz.VArhive is null OR fz.VArhive = 0)
  ORDER BY Id ASC
```

---

#### Что я пробовал?

1. Сначала мне показалось очень лаконичным решением с помощью `EXISTS` ,т.е.
   `EXISTS (SELECT CASE Sotrudnik WHEN Sotrudnik is null FROM GrafikOtpuskov WHERE Sotrudnik = fz.Id) as otp`
   Но как выяснилось его можно использовать только вместе с `WHERE`
2. Вернуть логическое значение прямо из запроса с помощью `CASE`, но у меня не вышло т.к. СУБД жаловалась на `is` около `null` 
   `(SELECT CASE Sotrudnik WHEN Sotrudnik is null THEN 'Нет' END AS sotr FROM GrafikOtpuskov WHERE Sotrudnik = fz.Id) as otp`
3. По изучал логические функции `ISNULL` и `COALESCE`, но они предлагают заменить `NULL`, что не совсем подходит к моей задачи

---

Возможно я не правильно применил найденные знания и скорей всего тут есть простое решение

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/2r7mRbv8

Comment: @Akina Спасибо большое за помощь

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 1000 
        fz.[Id]
      ,[FIO]
      ,kadr.TipTrudoustroystva
      ,kadr.Organizaciya
      ,kadr.Dolzhnostj
      ,CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT Sotrudnik FROM GrafikOtpuskov WHERE Sotrudnik = fz.Id) THEN 'Да' ELSE 'Нет' END as otp
FROM [ELMA3].[dbo].[FizicheskieLica] as fz
  INNER JOIN FizicheskieLica_KadrovayaIst AS kadr ON kadr.Parent = fz.Id 
  AND (kadr.TipTrudoustroystva = 'Основное' OR kadr.TipTrudoustroystva = 'Совмещение') 
  AND (kadr.DataUvoljneniya >= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) OR kadr.DataUvoljneniya is null)
  WHERE (fz.VArhive is null OR fz.VArhive = 0)
  ORDER BY Id ASC
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь